# Bash regex capture group

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm trying to match multiple alphanumeric values (this number could vary) from a string and save them to a bash capture group array. However, I'm only getting the first match:

```
mystring1='<link rel="self" href="/api/clouds/1/instances/1BBBBBB"/> dsf <link rel="self" href="/api/clouds/1/instances/2AAAAAAA"/>'

regex='/instances/([A-Z0-9]+)'

[[ $mystring1 =~ $regex ]]

echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
1BBBBBB

echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

As you can see- it matches the first value I'm looking for, but not the second.

Comment: Would you be content with looping over the output of `echo "$mystring1" | grep -oE '/instances/([A-Z0-9]+)'`?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the famous [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) post.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a shame that you can't do global matching in bash. You can do this:

```
global_rematch() { 
    local s=$1 regex=$2 
    while [[ $s =~ $regex ]]; do 
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        s=${s#*"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"}
    done
}
global_rematch "$mystring1" "$regex"
```

```
1BBBBBB
2AAAAAAA
```

This works by chopping the matched prefix off the string so the next part can be matched. It destroys the string, but in the function it's a local variable, so who cares.

I would actually use that function to populate an array:

```
$ mapfile -t matches < <( global_rematch "$mystring1" "$regex" )
$ printf "%s\n" "${matches[@]}"
1BBBBBB
2AAAAAAA
```

Comment: thanks- this looks like a viable solution- only issue is mapfile not existing in bash 3.2...

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for alternatives

Answer (score 18):

To get the second array value, you need to have a second set of parentheses in the regex:

```
mystring1='<link rel="self" href="/api/clouds/1/instances/1BBBBBB"/> dsf <link rel="self" href="/api/clouds/1/instances/2AAAAAAA"/>'

regex='/instances/([A-Z0-9]+).*/instances/([A-Z0-9]+)'

[[ $mystring1 =~ $regex ]]

$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
1BBBBBB
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
2AAAAAAA
```

Comment: Thanks, hoever I'm looking to match an unknown number of possible matches.

Comment: I upvoted your Q because I also expected multiple matches to go into the array, but they don't seem to, unless you actually have multiple sets of parentheses.