# Extract part of file between first occurrences of two strings fast

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have large (MB) text files containing a single line and need to extract the part between first occurrences of string1 and of string2.  I found many recipes but most work for separate lines or extract to the last occurrence of the second string.  The one I found that works using
parameters infile, outfile, string1, string2 is:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="$(cat $1)"                   ## copy file1 to a

a="$(echo "${a#*"$3"}")"        ## cut up to (including) str1  

echo "${a%%"$4"*}" > $2         ## part after str1 up to str2

## where the last line may also be

printf '%s' "${a%%"$4"*}" > $2  ## part after str1 up to str2
```

but both versions are terribly slow (I have to repeat this many times per file).  How speed up?

Comment: Is there some character in the single line that occurs a lot but isn't in your patterns that you can use `tr` to convert to a newline? If so then you can use one of the solutions you have found. I am thinking about perhaps a tab separated or comma separated set of fields? You should change `a="$(echo "${a#*"$3"}")"` to `a=${a#*"$3"}` to avoid creating subshells and copies of the data.

Comment: @icarus: change to a=${a#*"$3"} didn't speed up.  Breaking up into lines: I have been trying that but without success, still cannot just skip lines but need to skip everything between strings.  No single divider character.  I could split into many files with },{ as divider pattern and treat them all this way, is that faster?

Comment: What characters are in string 1 and string 2? Is this JSON?

Comment: I don't have the stetup to test what would actually speed things up, and I don't think I'll have time to figure out all the details today, but I suspect you could speed things up by compressing your operation into a single stream of grep or other regex statements? [This suggests `grep -oE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex#1891890) and [this shows how to do capture groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251013/bash-regex-capture-group). Of course a _compiled_ regex would be ideal.

Comment: I had to google JSON.  I put an example (a relatively small case) at http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/rrlnk/ads-suemoto.txt.  I extract per field between {...},{....} the title, author, bibcode fields.  A long sequence of mostly sed commands.  I will look into this stream suggestion - new to me.  Compiled regex???  Guess I need to learn.

Comment: Thank you for the example data. Very helpful. Can you expand a little more on "I extract per field..bibcode fields". What data do you want out of this line? Running `python -m json.tool ads-suemoto.txt` might give you some ideas. You probably want the `jq` tool,

Comment: Wow!   I had vowed to stick to IDL and never learn python, being too old. But I ran this command and the output in the terminal seems to split everything nicely.   What I want is the distillation in  http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/rrlnk/suemoto.txt which I get with http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/rrlnk/ads-name-abs but far too slowly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99538/discussion-between-icarus-and-rob-rutten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some discussion in chat with the OP exposed that the single line was JSON from a network query. Pretty printing this with tools such as `jq . < input_file` or `python -mjson.tool input_file` made the file more suitable for conventional line by line processing.

Further discussion yielded that this was a bibliographic lookup, and the intention was to produce a flat file. The following `jq` program (my first) is deemed by the OP to be fast enough.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                           

jq -r  < "$1" '.response.docs[] |                                                                                          
    ("    Title: "+.title[]),                                                                                                          
    ("   Authors: "+(.author|join(""))),                                                                                               
    ("    Bibcode: "+.bibcode),                                                                                                        
    ("   AltBibcode: "+(.alternate_bibcode//[] | join(" : "))),                                                                        
    ("  "+(.abstract//"NOABSTRACT")),                                                                                                  
    ""' | fmt | sed 's/^    \?//'
```

There are a couple of subtle points. The desire is to have the abstract wrapped rather than one long line, so the output is sent through `fmt`. This program has the property that lines starting with different indentations are **not** joined together, hence the 4/3/4/3/2 pattern of spaces in the text being added such as "    Title: ". fmt is then effectively just wrapping the abstract, indented by 2 spaces. The sed is then used to remove the 3 or 4 spaces that are on the other header lines. This is not perfect, very long lists of authors will get wrapped as well. A better sed program could join the authors back onto one line, remove blank AltBibcode entries etc.

The output format is designed so it can be post processed by an awk one line script

```
awk -vRS='' -vORS=$'\n\n' !/NOABSTRACT/'
```

to remove entries without abstracts.

Comment: If there are a lot of authors or long titles then changing `'s/^    \?//'` to `'/:/s/^    \?//'` can keep the continuation lines indented, at least until they start containing colons.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -e 's/stringA/\n/;s/.*\n//;s/stringB.*//' file
```

The removal of the code up to stringA is done in 2 stages (change stringA to newline and then remove the first line) rather than the more obvious "remove everything up to stringA" as the removal needs to be up to the **first** occurrence of stringA rather than the last. sed does not support non-greedy regular expressions, unlike many other tools such as python and perl.

```
$ perl -lpe '
    my($sa, $sb) = qw/stringA stringB/;
    my $p2 = index($_, $sb);
    my $p1 = index($_, $sa)+length($sa);
    $_ = substr($_, $p1, $p2-$p1);
'  file
```